# Using an existing MPPT charge controller and solar panels with new battery pack

Tags: lithium-ion, inverter, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I have an off-grid setup at the moment to power most of my DC devices (bulb, router, NAS, NVR, etc.)

I'm planning to upgrade my setup to a more powerful AC off-grid system to power my entire house.

My devices

- Two [JAM solar 460W panels](https://www.jasolar.com//uploadfile/2020/0619/20200619040220997.pdf) in parallel
- [Victron smart solar MPPT 100 1 20 charge controller](https://www.victronenergy.com/solar-charge-controllers/smartsolar-mppt-75-10-75-15-100-15-100-20)
- 12V 100AH deep cycle sealed lead acid battery

I'm planning to buy these new items:

- 4x SOK 206Ah lifepo4 batteries
- or 1x jakiper 48V 100Ah rack mount lifepo4 battery
- [Meanwell TS-3000 inverter](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/TS-3000/TS-3000-SPEC.PDF)

If I purchase this new equipment, can I use it with my existing PV array and charge controller, or do I need to add more panels or change my charge controller?

If can use them, do I need to connect the panels in series since each panel Voc is only 50.01V?

I was planning to buy a 12V inverter with one 12V LFP battery, but on many sites I saw that if making an off-grid setup with more than 3000W it is better go with a 48V system. Many sites suggest inverting from 48V->230V is better than 12V->230V. Is this true ? My usage is not more than 2000W, but for future improvement I would like to have a 3000W inverter.

Comment: The crucial question is whether your charge controller can be reprogrammed to correctly charge and protect LFP batteries. (I am assuming your choices of battery already have an appropriate BMS. Cheap charge controllers won't do the job. Yours isn't a cheap one, it's a Victron. So ... ask Victron. Their tech support is pretty good. (Otherwise : yes, 24 or 48V will be somewhat more efficient. Again : does your equipment support it?)

Comment: Thanks for this. I posted this question in Victron forums. The batteries I planning to buy got good BMS as reviewed by others. but  I'm not sure is there any compatibility issue with Victron controllers and certain BMS. I will test this. thanks again.